# Quadrics in $\mathbb{H}^3$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, hyperbolic-geometry

Consider a hyperbolic space $\mathbb{H}^3$ in the Beltrami-Klein model:
$$\mathbb{H}^3=\{(x,y,z|x^2+y^2+z^2\leq 1\}\subset \mathbb{R}^3.$$
Let $Q$ be a quadric in $\mathbb{R}^3.$

**Question:** What is a geometric meaning of $Q?$ What properties does it have?

Horospheres provide very special examples of such quadrics.

**Comment:** Here is an observation, which lead to this question. There is a natural way to associate an elliptic curve $E_Q\in \mathbb{P}^3_\mathbb{C}$ to $Q:$ 
consider an intersection of the complexification of $Q$ with complexification of the absolute: 
$$\partial \mathbb{H}^3=\{(x,y,z|x^2+y^2+z^2= 1\}.$$
Assume that the $Q$ bounds a domain in $\mathbb{H}^3$ of finite volume. Then this volume should be equal to the value of certain Riemann cross-ratio on $E_Q,$ because it is a period of 
$$H^3\left (\mathbb{P}^3\setminus Q_1, Q_2 \setminus (Q_1\cap Q_2)\right),$$
where $\mathbb{P}^3$, $Q_1$  and $Q_2$ are complexifications and projectivizations of $\mathbb{R}^3, \partial \mathbb{H}^3$ and $Q$ respectively.